# How to exclude folder in flutter test coverage?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, testing, widget

I have code using flutter, usually I use flutter test --coverage to see the percentage of code coverage

I have 5 folders in the test folder

```
for example : 
business_logic
presentation
utils
generated
services
```

how can i test 4 folders exclude presentation folder?
when I run the flutter test --coverage in my code takes 1.5 - 2 hours, that's why I want to exclude one of the folders

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter test --coverage
lcov --remove coverage/lcov.info "lib/business_logic/*" "lib/business_logic/*"
"lib/business_logic/*" "lib/generated/*""lib/services/*"
```